# PHP undefined chars ? in output

Tags: php, string, ascii

My problem is that i dont know from where those chars in my output, can anyone explain me why in my string are those characters and what ive to do to unset them ?

the function is used to change 'ä', 'ö', 'ü' into 'ae', 'oe', 'ue'

```
<?php

// str      | string argument
// needle   | searched char
// val      | value
// pos      | default 0 at start at offset zero 
// pos      | momently just working with default offset
function changeLetter($str, $needle, $val, $pos = 0) {
    $mstr = "";
    while (isset($str[$pos])) {            
        if (ord($str[$pos]) == ord($needle)) {
            $mstr .= $val;
            $pos++;
        } else {
            $mstr .= $str[$pos];
            $pos++;
        }
    }
    return $mstr;
}

echo changeLetter("täp@tecmax.com", 'ä', 'ae') . '<br>';
echo changeLetter("tüp@tecmax.com", 'ü', 'ue') . '<br>';
echo changeLetter("töp@tecmax.com", 'ö', 'oe') . '<br>';


//echo changeLetter("täp@tecmax.com", 'ä', 'ae', 3) . '<br>';   
?>
```

Output:

tae�p@tecmax.com

tue�p@tecmax.com

toe�p@tecmax.com

Comment: This chars uses more than one byte in string, thats why the chars are shown in this way, use str_replace to do your task.

Comment: Have you used [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)?

Comment: the problem is that my task is to programm this without str_replace / preg_replace etc

Comment: So, if you're not allowed to use the relevant built-in functions, sounds like homework or interview?

Comment: If this is a trick question, then it is probably to test you and your string/encoding knowledge, which you indeed seem to lack. → [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: its no homework, just a task to learn

Comment: I used `substr` .. let me know if you can not allowed to use that also .. then i can update my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do :

```
echo changeLetter("täp@tecmax.com", 'ä', 'ae'), PHP_EOL;
echo changeLetter("tüp@tecmax.com", 'ü', 'ue'), PHP_EOL;
echo changeLetter("töp@tecmax.com", 'ö', 'oe'), PHP_EOL;
```

Output

```
taep@tecmax.com
tuep@tecmax.com
toep@tecmax.com
```

Function Used

```
function changeLetter($str, $needle, $val, $pos = 0) {
    $next = function ($str, &$pos) {
        if (! isset($str[$pos]))
            return false;
        $char = ord($str[$pos]);
        if ($char < 128) {
            return $str[$pos ++];
        } else {
            if ($char < 224) {
                $bytes = 2;
            } elseif ($char < 240) {
                $bytes = 3;
            } elseif ($char < 248) {
                $bytes = 4;
            } elseif ($char = 252) {
                $bytes = 5;
            } else {
                $bytes = 6;
            }
            $str = substr($str, $pos, $bytes);
            $pos += $bytes;
            return $str;
        }
    };
    $mstr = "";
    while(($chr = $next($str, $pos)) !== false) {
        $mstr .= $chr == $needle ? $val : $chr;
    }
    return $mstr;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to change your file encoding, or use `&auml;`, `&uuml;`, `&ouml;` instead of `ä`, `ü`, `ö`.

Comment: Don't use HTML entities when you're not in an HTML context! Lucky for you I have used up my votes for today.